# Get All Processes With Their Corresponding App Domains

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process, appdomain

Is it possible to get a list of the running processes along with their corresponding app domains when running a program? I am aware *mscoree.dll* allows me to retrieve all App Domains of the **current** process using the **ICorRuntimeHost.EnumDomains** method. Is there a way to get this information **without** using an **external API** and just pure C# code? I understand mdbg has some functions that may help but I am not sure how to use this debugger. I am really looking for a solution using just C#.

Thanks

EDIT: 
The goal is to show every process running along with their corresponding app domains on an html page. Ideally there would be a function that iterates through all running processes and retrieves this information.

Code that retrieves all app domains for current process:

```
    private static List<AppDomainInf> GetAppDomains()
    {
        IList<AppDomain> mAppDomainsList = new List<AppDomain>();
        List<AppDomainInf> mAppDomainInfos = new List<AppDomainInf>();

        IntPtr menumHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        ICorRuntimeHost host = new CorRuntimeHost();

        try
        {
            host.EnumDomains(out menumHandle);
            object mTempDomain = null;

            //add all the current app domains running
            while (true)
            {
                host.NextDomain(menumHandle, out mTempDomain);
                if (mTempDomain == null) break;
                AppDomain tempDomain = mTempDomain as AppDomain;
                mAppDomainsList.Add((tempDomain));
            }

            //retrieve every app domains detailed information
            foreach (var appDomain in mAppDomainsList)
            {
                AppDomainInf domainInf = new AppDomainInf();

                domainInf.Assemblies = GetAppDomainAssemblies(appDomain);
                domainInf.AppDomainName = appDomain.FriendlyName;

                mAppDomainInfos.Add(domainInf);
            }

            return mAppDomainInfos;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw; //rethrow
        }
        finally
        {
            host.CloseEnum(menumHandle);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(host);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This requires a debugging function, ICorDebugProcess::EnumerateAppDomains().  Surely there's a better way to achieve what you want but the goal of this code is entirely invisible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however I am looking to avoid using any C++ libraries or imports IF possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using MdbgCore.dll located inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\MdbgCore.dll.:

```
CorPublish cp = new CorPublish();
foreach (CorPublishProcess process in cp.EnumProcesses())
            {
                    foreach (CorPublishAppDomain appDomain in process.EnumAppDomains())
                    {

                    }
                }
```